# non embedded postgresql in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven

I'm trying to use a non embedded PostgreSQL database in Spring Boot. But when I try to run my application "mvn spring-boot:run", the application fails to start with the following message:

**Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE**

These are my dependencies from pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Eureka service registration -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pew.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>backend-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

this is my settings in application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  application:
    name: resource-service
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    datasource:
      platform: postgres
      url: jdbc:postgresql://${postgresqlHost:localhost}:${postgresqlPort:5432}
      username: ${postgresqlUsername:root}
      password: ${postgresqlPassword:SomePassword}
      driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I can't find much information about this which makes me think that this is probably something really easy to get working...

Comment: The datasource property should be directly under spring, not under spring.jpa. All you need there is the url, username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute `"mvn spring-boot:run"` you don't specify to use the Spring Boot`dev` profile while you want to configure the datasource properties for the `dev` profile :

```
profiles: dev
```

Besides, in application.yml you should reference the property :
`spring.datasource` and not `jpa.database.datasource` that is not used by Spring.

You should write :

```
spring.datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${postgresqlHost:localhost}:${postgresqlPort:5432}
    ...
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-yaml-for-external-properties) is the documentation reference about the way to do it.

Comment: You are correct! I added the datasource under jpa by misstake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide database url and driver class name correctly

```
spring.datasource.url = <database source url>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = <driver class name>
```